# What permissions do I need to give my user to run "shutdown -r 5" command from cron?

Tags: linux, bash, shutdown, cron

I’m have a bash script that I run in /etc/crontab on Linux

```
$ uname -a
Linux mymachine.com 3.4.76-65.111.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jan 14 21:06:49 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The bash script contains a line

```
sudo shutdown -r 5
```

However, when the cron job runs (as a user named “myuser”), the machine is never rebooted and I instead find this in the logs

```
[sudo] password for myuser:
```

What do I need to do to give this user the ability to reboot from cron?  It’s not an option to run this script as another user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a line in `/etc/sudoers` that reads:

```
myuser ALL = NOPASSWD:  /sbin/shutdown
```

The `NOPASSWD` part tells `sudo` to let `myuser` run the shutdown command with providing a password.

To add such a line to `/etc/sudoers`, run (as root):

```
sudoedit /etc/sudoers
```

`sudoedit` will scan your updated version of the file for errors before installing it.  Consequently, this is safer than editing the file directly.